# Where does the python startup text come from

Tags: python, python-2.7

This question is purely because of my curiousity - when I type python, I see

```
$python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 12:56:24) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Where is this text coming from - particularly `(default, Mar  1 2015, 12:57:24)` and `on linux 2`?. The rest is fairly self explanatory, and I can find hints at where it comes in the file `/usr/bin/python2.7-config`

I tried `touch`ing `/usr/bin/python2.7` and found out that doesn't change the time.

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask - if it is, is there anywhere else on stackexchange I could ask?

Comment: I believe that is the build time of your Python.

Comment: That's the time Python was built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part comes from `Py_GetVersion()`, which is equivalent to `sys.version`. In the end, `Py_GetBuildInfo()` is called, and it appears it gets that information from the C macros `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`. Check out the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/getbuildinfo.c) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

These texts are in the Python binary itself, put there at the time it's built.

The compilation timestamp comes from the [standard C macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`.

The compiler version information comes from the GCC `__VERSION__` macro (which is also available on Clang).

The `linux2` comes from a macro called `PLATFORM` in the Python source, probably fed to the compiler via the makefile.